Insight into basic machine translation error from major email service
I recently ordered a product through a Japanese company (I live in Tokyo), and received an email response that due to a recent backlog of orders I should expect my product shipped within 2-3 weeks (in business days). One verbatim sentence is reproduced below, and uses standard polite Japanese, clearly understandable to me (JLPT-N2).
「大変申し訳ございません只今注文が混みあっており、ご注文頂いた商品は営業日で約２～３週間以内での発送予定となっております。」
The surprising aspect is that when I clicked automatic translation (this is all within Gmail; the same result appears when using a dedicated Google Translate app), the following line resulted (the entire email was broken into discrete lines).
"We apologize for the inconvenience, but we are currently experiencing a high volume of orders, and your ordered items will be shipped within approximately 2-3 business days."
My question, which may not have a definitive answer from the above, is why a presumably mature machine translation service confuses/overlooks an basic distinction between weeks (週間）and days (日間)? Is Gmail's built-in translation service currently run through some sort of LLM-adjacent process which has made the output fuzzy, picking up on the directly preceding 営業日 (on further experimentation, removing this word corrects the output, but why)? Some surrounding sentences from the email are also made considerably less idomatic, which is more understandable, but the above error is a basic one of quantity.

My understanding is that Google translate has always made significant use of pattern-matching (forerunner of LLM) rather than any sort of analysis. When I used to read LanguageLog regularly, there were frequent posts analysing Google Translate's egregious errors.

I'm not sure what sort of answer could be given here. Neural networks are, by design, an impenetrable black box. There's no way to know "why" a particular thing happened.

You might be able to find a better answer at the [ai.se] site.

@Draconis By playing with the input to generate more examples, I am often able to figure out what is going on.  (I used to be an engineer at Google Translate, but I did the same thing when I worked there.)

@ColinFine is right, this is not new, for translation.  The “T” in “GPT” was invented inside Google, for translation (and published in 2017).
